# SQL logs showing login that I can't find

Tags: sql-server, security

Within my SQL server logs, I am showing a successful login to a database from an account (`SERVER\loginname`) that I cannot find in either `Security > Logins` OR `Database > Security > Users`. This login is being used by a program to execute a task (which it does successfully), so it's not a security compromise, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where it is and I need to find it to make an adjustment.

A couple more notes: I do remember adding this specific login a while back and there was something special about how I had to do it because it is not a domain account. Instead, it uses pass through authentication (same local account name on the app and SQL server with the same password). I cannot use it to login via SSMS. It is not a part of a group membership. It is not showing when I do a `SELECT` from the master `syslogins` table.

Does anyone have any ideas for my brain-fart?

Comment: Did you look in [`sys.server_principals`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) which replaces `sys.syslogins` if you're on 2005+? I would *triple* check group membership if you still can't see it in there.

Comment: @JonSeigel `sys.server_principals` also isn't showing it. And I know it isn't a group membership because I don't have any groups that have ownership to that database. I'm completely dumbfounded right now.

Comment: To confirm, BUILTIN\Administrators and BUILTIN\Users are not logins on the instance, correct?

Comment: @MattyZDBA That is correct. These logins are a part of the BUILTIN\Administrators group, _but_ it is not mapped to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running the following:

```
EXEC xp_logininfo @acctname = 'SERVER\loginname', @option='all';
```

This should return the SQL login the Windows user is being authenticated as.

Reference [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190369.aspx).

Comment: Well, we're getting somewhere. It is saying that it is a part of the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group. However, this group is NOT mapped to that database. I have double and triple checked at both the `Security > Logins` level as well as `Database > Security > Users`. How is that possible that it is still authenticating successfully without it being explicitly mapped?

Comment: By default, BUILTIN\Administrators is mapped to the sysadmin fixed server role and therefore has the same permissions as the SA login

Comment: @MattyZDBA The owner of the database is not `sa`, however. I am using a separate sysadmin credential for ownership. Or would that not matter? To further troubleshoot, I have also eliminated all users from the database except `dbo`, `guest`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and `sys`. I am suspecting it is under the `dbo` login. However, I attempted to use another local administrator account that is setup exactly like this one (credentials on both app and SQL for pass-through) to execute the task in the program, and I am getting _Login unsuccesful_.

Comment: Does BUILTIN\Administrators have a login on the server? And if so, is it a member of one of the fixed server roles? The fixed server roles will provide database-level access without having a user account in a database.